# Firebase get child ID swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase looks like this. Bellow `Active_Orders` it appear `childs` with different names depending on their `UID`(user ID).

[image]

And this is my code to get the child's ID no matter what the name is. But it does not seem to work at all. Whats the proper way to get the `child ID`? Thanks

```
databaseRef.child("Active_Orders").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: {
                    snapshot in
                //Get customerUID
                let customerUID = snapshot.value!.objectForKey("username") as! String
                self.setText("customerUID", value: customerUID)
```

Comment: Give your minimal but suffise JSON tree.. not a snippet but as a text..

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the question: In this case, you want customerUID to be equal to "ZDitJoAnqES6PPO3teK0EDQnGXJ2", correct?

Comment: No, I want to print out the the name/ID of "Active_Orders -> Child"

Comment: So you want to print a list of all active orders?

Comment: Yes, I but I only want to get the name of the childs. To send it further.

Comment: When you say name of the childs, do you mean like "ZDitJoAnqES6PPO3teK0EDQnGXJ2" would be the name of the child in this picture?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Try out the code in my answer and see if it gets you what you need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is hard to tell from your question exactly what you are doing, but does this get you the list you  need?

```
databaseRef.child("Active_Orders").observeEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in 
    if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for child in result {
            var orderID = child.key as! String
            print(orderID)
        }
    }
})
```

I believe this block should iterate over all the children that are inside "Active_Orders" and print out their key value (which seems to be what you are trying to print).

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3 and Firebase 4

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()   

ref.child("Active_orders").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    if !snapshot.exists() {return} //may want to add better error handling here.

    let info = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

    print("info keys are:", info.allKeys)
})
```